# Android get project name bash

Tags: android, bash, awk

I would like to extract the value app_name contained in string.xml but I dont know how to do that:

Here is what I have

```
appName=`awk -F'"' '/android:label/{print $(NF-1); exit}' AndroidManifest.xml`
echo "App name is "$appName
```

this prints 
@string/app_name

but what I would like is the actual string contained there, how could I do that in bash script please:
something like

```
#totally wrong
appName2=`awk -F'"' '$appName{print $(NF-1); exit}' res/values/strings.xml`
echo "App name is "$appName2 #this prints "utf-8"
```

also if anyone knows of simple and quick tutorials for awk I'd be grateful

thanks

EDIT: xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="other">Other</string>
  <string name="app_name">App Name</string>
  <string name="other2">Other</string>
</resources>
```

Thks to all that have answered here is the final version:

```
appName=`awk -F'["/]' '/android:label/{print $(NF-1); exit}' AndroidManifest.xml`
echo "App name is "$appName

appName2=`xpath -q -e "//*[@name='$appName']/text()" res/values/strings.xml`
echo $appName2
```

Comment: use xpath to extract the value. can you show the input xmls?

Comment: could you explain how wit an example please? also hav edited my question and added xml file

Comment: yeah, will give an example

Comment: I do not see `android:label` in you xml file.  Where do you get it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xpath:

```
xpath -q -e "//*[@name='app_name']/text()" AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: Not a standard program in Ubuntu and have to be installed.  Why use it when a simple `awk` gets what we need?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (not very portable) with `awk`:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '/"app_name"/ {print $3}'
```

With your example, output is `App Name`.

Short explanation: it changes the input field separator with angle brackets, then the awk command take the 3rd field if the line matches `"app_name"`.

Answer (score 0):

This awk with different file separator will work:

```
awk -F'["/]' '/android:label/{print $(NF-1); exit}' AndroidManifest.xml
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
app_name
```

Comment: thanks but I would like to get what is inside "app_name" not app name itself

Comment: I have provided the example xml in edit, so what I would like to print is App Name

Answer (score 0):

Example using xpath:

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="other">Other</string>
  <string name="app_name">App Name</string>
  <string name="other2">Other</string>
</resources>
```

Command:

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[@name="app_name"]/text()' test.xml
```

you need the xmllint package installed for that